# Importing HH:MM:SS time values results in "Invalid format string" when using plot_date

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, strftime

I have been trying to make a simple plot with an x-axis in the format HH:MM:SS with the values taken from a file in the same format. I'm using numpy.loadtxt and a converter to read the times and values as follows:

`time, moisture = np.loadtxt(dirlist[0], usecols=(1,2), unpack=True, converters = {1: dates.strpdate2num("%H:%M:%S")})`

However, when I plot using date_plot, I receive the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 276, in resize
    self.show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 348, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1091, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 945, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 893, in iter_ticks
    for i, val in enumerate(majorLocs)]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 524, in __call__
    return self._formatter(x, pos)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 375, in __call__
    return self.strftime(dt, self.fmt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 413, in strftime
    s1 = time.strftime(fmt, (year,) + timetuple[1:])
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

As it looks to me that its complaining about a missing year, I decided to check the parsed date using `num2date` and the correct date of `1900-01-01 11:10:41+00:00` was returned although I don't know why there is an `+00:00`. Could this be the source of my woes?

Even though `strpdate2num` is parsing correctly, I decided to check if I add a `YYYY:MM:DD` to the beginning of the times within the file would it work and low and behold it did. Unfortunately, I'd rather not append a `YYYY:MM:DD` to the beginning of every time value so, finally my question is: how do I get plot_date to work while reading in a time without an `YYYY:MM:DD` prefix and why is `strpdate2num` not taking care of this?

Cheers,
Dave

As requested, a snippet of the input file:

```
0.465752314814815   11:10:41    9.086096129
0.466226851851852   11:11:22    8.346124754
0.466701388888889   11:12:03    8.179795013
0.467175925925926   11:12:44    8.364891272
0.467662037037037   11:13:26    8.147598262
0.468136574074074   11:14:07    8.35810013
0.468611111111111   11:14:48    8.333816653
0.469085648148148   11:15:29    8.41123069
0.469085648148148   11:15:29    8.130661712
0.469560185185185   11:16:10    3.131862435
```

Here is my code:

```
datefunc = lambda x: dates.date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S'))

times, moisture = np.loadtxt(dirlist[0], delimiter='\t', usecols=(1,2), converters={1: datefunc}, unpack=True) 

times_date=[]

for t in times:
    times_date.append(dates.num2date(t)) #Converting back to a datetime object

plt.plot_date(times_date , moisture, xdate=True)
# plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Comment: At a quick glance it looks like the first column is your time, so shouldn't the converter be {0 : dates.strpdate2num...} (a 0 not a 1)?

Comment: Nope, the first column is irrelevant data which I'm ignoring. The time data is in the second column while moisture values are in the third column.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I missed that. I've just tried a small example and it works ok for me, could you post a couple of lines from your input file?

Comment: Also, the +00:00 is your time zone (looks like you're in GMT).

Comment: Cheers Tim, will do. I think my issue is that I'm not creating a datetime object, merely a decimal time.

Comment: You might have more luck with the python datetime module's strptime function. It's very similar to strpdate2num but might better support time only strings.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought strpdate2num invoked strptime i.e. date2num(strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S")). I'll give it a shot anyway. Cheers Tim

Comment: I tried creating a converter lambda function using date2num(strptime(i, "%H:%M:%S")) then convert back to a datetime object using num2date however, plot_date still throws the same error. I have added a code snippet above to show what I am doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a strange problem as you're original code looks ok. This works for me in Python 2 (Python 3 requires conversion from byte data). I have tried this with your example data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num
import numpy as np

time, val = np.loadtxt("File.txt", usecols=(1,2), unpack=True, converters = {1: strpdate2num("%H:%M:%S")})

plt.plot_date(time, val)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So this got me thinking, I was compiling on a windows partition. Neither Idle nor sublime text was working so switched to Ubuntu and compiled there. It worked fine...strange. What OS are you using Tim? Also, cheers for the help.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm using Linux (Arch Linux) with matplotlib version 1.4.2.